# Removing spam links

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

Why is not advisable to remove spam links? such as the following:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/should-the-constant-pi-be-considered-harmful-closed

I removed the URL but for some reason it has been put back.

And also I noticed that the tag 'pi' has been put back, but I had removed that tag.

Comment: why you consider it spam link, actually?.. btw, revision history says that it was Isaac♦ who did rollback

Comment: (but I hope [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/should-the-constant-pi-be-considered-harmful-closed) question will be deleted)

Comment: I don't think that link is a spam (undiscriminated bulk advertisement). In fact, the link is used as an argument for the OP to consider π harmful.

Comment: Also, why do you want to remove the tag?

Comment: Look here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-removed

tag-removed makes it easier to avoid coming rubbish when you are searching. It's useful to detag these sorts of questions then.

Comment: @muad: If you want to avoid closed questions, just add `closed:0` to the search term.

Comment: @muad: If this question is so bad that it should not come up in search results for the `pi` tag, then it should be deleted. But I think that the question, regardless of its quality, is definitely about pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a question or answer does contain a spam link, please remove it.
In this case, it appears that the link is being used as a reference for a question, and indeed, the text of the question:

> Reading the post by Michael Hartl, it
>   sounds rather convincing. Taking
>   circumference to diameter ratio, as
>   opposed to radius, looks like a
>   historical mistake.
>
> Do you have other opinions? Welcome to
>   the community wiki.

seems much less useful without the link. Anyone who wants to answer such a question will likely end up searching for the same link themselves.

Now, if the question itself is just a spam question intended to promote the tau manifesto site, that's a different story. I don't see any reason to conclude this yet. It seems plausible that this is a real question that someone wants to know the answer to.

As for retagging the question `tag-removed`, any question that is so bad nobody would want it to come up in their search results is best deleted. For example, a question that is so off-topic it fits no existing tags, and was mistagged by the person who asked it. Vote to delete such questions, or flag them for a moderator to delete.